# Restrict the client access to a Plex Media Server to user specified IP addresses

Tags: networking, server, dlna, plex

To play videos from my computer on my television I am using `Plex Media Server`. Unfortunately, with `Plex Media Server` running, any device on my LAN can access this `DLNA server`.

I want to restrict the client access to the `Plex Media Server` to a selection of local IP addresses, but I can't seem to find such an option in the program. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your default firewall is ufw

ufw has a graphical front end, gufw

You allow access to your desired IP, and deny from the rest.

You need to identify the ports your plex server is listening on and ip you wish to allow.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw

If you need more specific assistance, please update your question with additional details.

Comment: Quite a nice solution. Do I understand that `Plex Media Server` does not have a built-in option to restrict client access to certain IP addresses? The `DLNA server` program `MediaTomb`, for instance, does have this option built in. It would be much simpler if `Plex Media Server` had a similar option.

Comment: You would have to configure PLEX, assuming this is an option. See - https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/201181926-Restricted-Access-via-Multi-User . Personally, for what you want, ufw / gufw is a simple solution.